# In mechanical turk, How to limit a HIT is accept by one worker

Tags: mechanicalturk

In mechanical turk, How to limit a HIT is accept by one worker, after the first one is finished other worker can accept it. The HIT is just accepted by one work per time. It has many assignments during the life time.
Specifically, One HIT is finished by worker in sequence: one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality to do this. Using the API and your own server, you could configure your own application that accepts [Notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/Concepts_NotificationsArticle.html) from MTurk, e.g. HITCompleted or AssignmentSubmitted, and then trigger new assignments and/or HITs.

Comment: thanks, it seems a little complicated. Right now, I use the command Line tools with external website. So the command line tools can not manage this?

Comment: @yongnan No, you need to design an application that is responsive to incoming requests (probably something setup on a web server). Command-line tools will not achieve that.